# How to use Like in Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch the EmployeeId whose first, lastname or middlename contains the passed value.

This is my code.

```
if(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("KeyName") == "employee_name")
{
if(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("SearchType") == "Alert"){
key = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PassedValue")
if(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("Operator")=="Contains"){
def  res = sql.rows("SELECT AlertID FROM AlertEmployeeRel where EmployeeID=(Select ID from Employee where [FirstName] like '%$key%' or [LastName]='%$key%' or [MiddleName]='%$key%')")
log.info(res.AlertID)
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("tempPassedValue",res.AlertID.toString())
}
```

This is NOT working.. Getting following error

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

can any one let me know how to use Like in SubQuery?

Comment: Is that ALL of your code?   The error does not match the single query in here.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has nothing to do with `LIKE`.  Use `IN` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT aerAlertID
FROM AlertEmployeeRel aer
WHERE aer.EmployeeID  IN (Select e.ID 
                          FROM Employee e
                          WHERE e.FirstName like '%$key%' or e.LastName = '%$key%' or e.MiddleName = '%$key%'
                         );
```

Comment: Getting following error "Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: @ChanGan . . . I don't understand the error.  There *is* only one expression in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: This is not the error, the one you fixed is "Subquery returns more than 1 row".

Comment: I have one row.. subquery returns only one row when run alone

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a concern, you can use the `EXISTS` operator. `EXISTS` is generally more efficient than `IN` when dealing with a lot of data because it stops searching for a value once the first match is made. Also, make sure you also use the `like` operator for LastName and MiddleName.

```
SELECT aerAlertID
FROM AlertEmployeeRel aer
WHERE aer.EmployeeID EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM Employee e
                      WHERE e.ID = aer.EmployeeID
                      AND (e.FirstName like '%$key%'
                      OR e.LastName like '%$key%'
                      OR e.MiddleName like '%$key%')
                      );
```